# aws s3 restored image files, has the extension jpg, but were all gzip

Tags: amazon-s3, restore, amazon-glacier, rclone, cloudberry

we had some files stored in AWS S3 in the storage class of Glacier Deep Archive, and they have been restored and can be downloaded.

all of them are images and videos.

when i download it directly from browser, it is ok, all can be opened normally.

but when i download them from any one of the following methods :

1. rclone
2. aws cli
3. aws explorer via vscode plugin

all image files carry the jpg extension, but none of them can be opened.
upon a check on the file type, they are all in fact gzip files.
after i rename their extension, they can be unzipped and viewed as images.

the same also applies to video files.

so, have i missed anything in maybe the rclone copy / sync command which can include the above manual file extension conversion during the copy / sync ?

those files were backuped via CloudBerry, would that be the origin of this whole thing ( which i might have misconfigured ) ?

Comment: Cloudberry Backup used to have a "Simple Mode" that would store files in Amazon s3 in their original form. This was great for access outside of the backup tool. However, if your backup was configured with a different mode, then the files would be stored in a different format. It would _appear_ that it zipped the files to save storage space and to make uploads faster. Browsers automatically understand gzip compression and, it would seem, coincidently unzipped the files for you. Start by checking the Cloudberry Backup configuration.